# How to move a large amount of files off a SharePoint 2003 Portal Server to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2007, migration, 2003

We're currently trying to move a considerable amount of files off our old SP 2007 site. At first we were doing this manually, but this would take many months, so we thought we could employ a PowerShell script to copy the files from the document libraries to HDD, then HDD to SharePoint Online. Unfortunately, we discovered that the site actually uses the SharePoint Portal Server from 2003, and the server doesn't have PowerShell. Is there any type of workaround we could implement so we don't have to manually move 100k+ files? Maybe somehow install PowerShell on the portal server? If we can at least get them onto a hard disk, we already have tool for transferring them into SharePoint Online, we just want the files off the site without having to manually do so.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution would be to upgrade up to a point where either SPMT or Migration Manager could take over the migration process.
I believe that the lower boundary for the above tools is that the Sharepoint Server is at least 10. So that would mean that you would have to upgrade from 2003 to moss 2007 and from there to sharepoint 2010.

Another solution, would be to check out the third party tools and their compatibility with the SPS 2003(Honestly, i do not think that there is still any tool that could handle such a task).

A third option is something that i used in order to migrate a portion of files from our own on-premises moss 2010 to out online tennant, just to see if it is applicable.
**I am not sure if you can use this solution**, but i will type it down so that you can try it out.

Moss 2010 gave you the option to open a Document Library as a network mapped drive.
So what i did was :

1. open a network mapped drive on the fileserver, in which case a letter is assigned to the drive.
2. write a simple script with the robocopy command just to utilise the parallel functionality of cloning folders that it has in order to get the files that i needed in the FileServer.
3. Use SPMT that pointed to that file location and upload all of the data.

If in any case you wish to proceed with testing out this solution, i would like to stress out that while copying files over the network with the parallel option, in robocopy, enabled did create a huge load to the sharepoint server. I'm just stating that because, i, also, attempted to upload files to an network mapped drive that pointed to a SharePoint Online Document Library. The result of the above was that the connection was cut off after a couple of minutes :)

One of the drawbacks was that permissions and file modification dates were not preserved, but i believe that since you are trying to migrate something that is as old as SPS 2003, this will be the least of your concerns.